# Remove 'bubble icon' before comments in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am new to Wordpress and I decided to install the Simple Life Theme (https://wordpress.org/support/theme/simple-life/)

In front of the link/text how many people commented, there is a 'bubble icon'. I want to replace this with my own comment. Any tips how I can do this?

Cheers!

I tried to Google it and even tried Chat GPT. Chat GPT told me to use:

```
.comments-link {
    display: none;
}
```

But this removes everything including text. Second prompt he advised this, but it only add my icon and the bubble icon is still there:

```
.comments-link {
    background-image: url('path-to-icon-file');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please find the [policy on GPT](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). My opinion: Don't waste brain cycles. (And there is neither `he` nor *they*, as of 2023.)